Broken links and missing blobs in Github repository - can no longer commit to main, how can I restore normal behavior?
When I run git fsck --full, I get:
git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
broken link from    tree edf233cad03998f924b63d03542a9c0d4cd5ad51
              to    blob bce7d316531d4898377090bec22ad56fd4705c9c
broken link from    tree 906930905a7bd388cce21a4c33ea044d2a748fda
              to    blob 2a8d5a0efc1d84d40c1253920eeff8f608d9de93
missing blob bce7d316531d4898377090bec22ad56fd4705c9c
missing blob 2a8d5a0efc1d84d40c1253920eeff8f608d9de93
missing blob 316f61a6235860af13777c4cb525cacf7ecfb130

In Github Desktop, when I select the latest commit, I get "fatal: unable to read bce7d316531d4898377090bec22ad56fd4705c9c". This file is not important for me to have backed up. I simply wish to restore functionality to Github Desktop so I can continue to use it for version control.
How do I repair my files or restore function to Github Desktop? And how do I avoid a situation like this one in the future?
From reading online, it seems it occurs when you interrupt a push, but nothing of the sort happened. I simply tried to commit to main one day and found my files corrupted.
Happy to provide further info as needed.
I've tried going to .git/objects and deleting this file, but it has not remedied the situation.
I've read git repair can help, but after installing ghcup, and then running 'cabal update', 'cabal install cabal-install', and finally 'cabal install git-repair --bindir=$HOME/bin', I find I'm still missing dependencies. This tool was designed for Linux users and I'm on Windows 10, and having trouble getting it to work for me.

> $ cabal install git-repair Resolving dependencies... Error: cabal.exe:
> Could not resolve dependencies: [__0] trying: git-repair-1.20230814
> (user goal) [__1] trying:
> git-repair:setup.Cabal-3.10.2.0/installed-00ad (dependency of
> git-repair) [__2] next goal: git-repair:setup.unix (dependency of
> git-repair) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.5.1,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.5.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.4.0,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.3.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.2.1,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.2.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.1.1,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.1.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.8.0.0,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.3, git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.2.2,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.2.1, git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.2.0 (library
> is not buildable in the current environment, but it is required by
> git-repair) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.1.0 (conflict:
> git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.5 && <4.9) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.0.1, git-repair:setup.unix-2.7.0.0
> (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.5 && <4.8) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.6.0.1, git-repair:setup.unix-2.6.0.0
> (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.5 && <4.7) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.5.1.1, git-repair:setup.unix-2.5.1.0
> (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.5 && <4.6) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.5.0.0 (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.2 && <4.5) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.4.2.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.4.1.0
> (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.2 && <4.4) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.4.0.2, git-repair:setup.unix-2.4.0.1
> (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.2 && <4.3) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.4.0.0 (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base>=4.1 && <4.3) [__2] rejecting: git-repair:setup.unix-2.3.2.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.3.1.0,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.3.0.0, git-repair:setup.unix-2.2.0.0,
> git-repair:setup.unix-2.0 (conflict: git-repair:setup.Cabal =>
> git-repair:setup.base==4.19.1.0/installed-6554, git-repair:setup.unix
> => git-repair:setup.base<4.3) [__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: git-repair, git-repair:setup.Cabal, git-repair:setup.unix) After
> searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
> goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: git-repair:setup.base,
> git-repair:setup.unix, git-repair, git-repair:setup.Cabal Try running
> with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.


I've tried amending commit, undoing commit, and revert changes in commit, and none of them seemed to have helped. An error message pops up, to the effect of action failed because of the same error. My local drive no longer has the latest versions of my files (although thankfully at least some of them appears to be on Github), and I'm worried meddling further will lose me my most recent changes altogether.
